# Using jQuery to select both a radio button and select value

Tags: jquery, html

I require the use of a button which selects multiple form attributes simultaneously, namely a *radio button*, *checkbox* and a *SELECT option value*. I am not too clued up on jQuery, currently I have a nice way of using a button to trigger the selection of a radio button (working example at http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/)

Ideally I would like to know if it could work within the method used in that site.

My SELECT values look like this:

```
<label for="testc">TestC</label>
   <div class="input-box">
   <select name="testc[]" id="testc" class="multiselect" title="TestC" multiple="multiple" size="4">
   <option value="3" >Yes</option>
   <option value="4" >No</option>
   <option value="5" >Maybe</option>
   </select>    
   </div>
```

I thought it might be done by adding a string command similar to:

```
$( "#testc" ).val();
```

... although not sure if this is correct to use or not.

Comment: did you try it .... did you face any problem while trying it

Comment: Yes I tried unsuccessfully. My problem was that I didn't know how to define a SELECT option value inside the jquery code, like the way they define the input type of a checkbox:


'$('input:radio[name=sex]:nth(2)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[2].checked = true;'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/oyvwxrok/1/)**

```
$("#isSelect").click(function () {
    $("#selected").empty();
    var radioValue=$('input:radio[name=sex]:checked').val();
    $("#selected").append(radioValue);
    $("#selected").append("<br/>");

    $('.multiselect :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
         $("#selected").append($(selected).val()); 
         $("#selected").append("<br/>");
    });

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i,checked){
        $("#selected").append($(checked).val()); 
         $("#selected").append("<br/>");
    });
});
```